# Extension Won't Debug

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, vsix

I have a VSIX package in a 2015 Solution, targetting VS2013. Whenever I try to run it against the VS2013 Experimental Instance, the extension doesn't show up in the installed list.

However, I am able to manually install the `.vsix` file into 2013 by double clicking on it. This will install (and run) successfully.

The settings for creating the `.vsix` and deploying it to Exp appear to be correct. What am I missing?

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PackageManifest Version="2.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vsx-schema/2011" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vsx-schema-design/2011">
    <Metadata>
        <Identity Id="9D7E0DF5-0A4D-4B43-9D73-4AD3F83260FA" Version="1.2" Language="en-US" Publisher="VersionOne" />
        <DisplayName>VersionOne TFS Checkin Policy</DisplayName>
        <Description xml:space="preserve">TFS Checkin policy from VersionOne for Visual Studio 2013.  Requires code commits to contain a VersionOne identifier</Description>
        <License>LICENSE.md</License>
        <Icon>logo.ico</Icon>
    </Metadata>
    <Installation>
        <InstallationTarget Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro" Version="[12.0]" />
        <InstallationTarget Version="[12.0]" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Premium" />
        <InstallationTarget Version="[12.0]" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Ultimate" />
    </Installation>
    <Dependencies>
        <Dependency Id="Microsoft.Framework.NDP" DisplayName="Microsoft .NET Framework" d:Source="Manual" Version="[4.5]" />
    </Dependencies>
    <Assets>
        <Asset Type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.VsPackage" d:Source="File" Path="RegistryKeyToAdd.pkgdef" />
    </Assets>
</PackageManifest>
```

**Project File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <MinimumVisualStudioVersion>14.0</MinimumVisualStudioVersion>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">11.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
    <FileUpgradeFlags>
    </FileUpgradeFlags>
    <OldToolsVersion>12.0</OldToolsVersion>
    <UpgradeBackupLocation>
    </UpgradeBackupLocation>
    <PublishUrl>publish\</PublishUrl>
    <Install>true</Install>
    <InstallFrom>Disk</InstallFrom>
    <UpdateEnabled>false</UpdateEnabled>
    <UpdateMode>Foreground</UpdateMode>
    <UpdateInterval>7</UpdateInterval>
    <UpdateIntervalUnits>Days</UpdateIntervalUnits>
    <UpdatePeriodically>false</UpdatePeriodically>
    <UpdateRequired>false</UpdateRequired>
    <MapFileExtensions>true</MapFileExtensions>
    <ApplicationRevision>0</ApplicationRevision>
    <ApplicationVersion>1.0.0.%2a</ApplicationVersion>
    <IsWebBootstrapper>false</IsWebBootstrapper>
    <UseApplicationTrust>false</UseApplicationTrust>
    <BootstrapperEnabled>true</BootstrapperEnabled>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile />
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{82b43b9b-a64c-4715-b499-d71e9ca2bd60};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <ProjectGuid>{2153C73F-1BA9-49F8-BAB2-84F7769BD67A}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>VersionOne.Integration.Tfs.Policy.Deployment.VS2013</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>VersionOne.Integration.Tfs.Policy.VS2013</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <GeneratePkgDefFile>false</GeneratePkgDefFile>
    <IncludeAssemblyInVSIXContainer>false</IncludeAssemblyInVSIXContainer>
    <IncludeDebugSymbolsInVSIXContainer>false</IncludeDebugSymbolsInVSIXContainer>
    <IncludeDebugSymbolsInLocalVSIXDeployment>false</IncludeDebugSymbolsInLocalVSIXDeployment>
    <CopyBuildOutputToOutputDirectory>false</CopyBuildOutputToOutputDirectory>
    <CopyOutputSymbolsToOutputDirectory>false</CopyOutputSymbolsToOutputDirectory>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <CreateVsixContainer>True</CreateVsixContainer>
    <DeployExtension>True</DeployExtension>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="..\VersionOne.Integration.Tfs.Policy.Deployment.Shared\logo.ico">
      <Link>logo.ico</Link>
      <IncludeInVSIX>true</IncludeInVSIX>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="..\VersionOne.Integration.Tfs.Policy.Deployment.Shared\RegistryKeyToAdd.pkgdef">
      <Link>RegistryKeyToAdd.pkgdef</Link>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <IncludeInVSIX>true</IncludeInVSIX>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="..\VersionOne.Integration.Tfs.Policy.Deployment.Shared\LICENSE.md">
      <Link>LICENSE.md</Link>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <IncludeInVSIX>true</IncludeInVSIX>
    </Content>
    <None Include="app.config" />
    <None Include="source.extension.vsixmanifest">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <ProductName>Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 %28x86 and x64%29</ProductName>
      <Install>true</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Net.Client.3.5">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <ProductName>.NET Framework 3.5 SP1 Client Profile</ProductName>
      <Install>false</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Net.Framework.3.5.SP1">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <ProductName>.NET Framework 3.5 SP1</ProductName>
      <Install>false</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\VersionOne.Integration.Tfs.Policy.VS2013\VersionOne.Integration.Tfs.Policy.VS2013.csproj">
      <Project>{24b4af99-795b-4b33-ad1d-fd51f32e2aeb}</Project>
      <Name>VersionOne.Integration.Tfs.Policy.VS2013</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\VSSDK\Microsoft.VsSDK.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
       Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  </Target>
  -->
</Project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure your project to deploy to VS2013, even when run from VS2015.

Sam Harwell wrote a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/VSSDK.IDE.Deploy.12/) that does exactly that; just install that package and you should be good to go.